# Change Backup policy for the Azure VM under Recovery services vault

Tags: backup, azure

It might seem quite obvious but it's not.

My question is how to change backup policy for particular VM, which is already configured to use another policy in the Recovery services vault?

Just to be clear, we're talking about Azure VM backup. So I can't add VM to Associated items of another policy, because It's already configured with the first one.

My thoughts to resolve this:

Stop backup for the VM, retain data. Configure backup again, but now with different policy. This would show some errors in backup alerts as the backup will be stopped.

Any though how to resolve this in more elegant way?

Answer (score 2):

You can go to replicated items and from backup policy, click on its name and then you change to a new one. See this image [Change policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxJMz.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the backup policy programmatically as well. See [MS Doc: Change policy for backup items](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-automation#change-policy-for-backup-items)

PowerShell example from the above doc:

```
$TargetPol1 = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy `
  -Name <PolicyName> -VaultId $targetVault.ID
$anotherBkpItem = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -WorkloadType AzureVM -BackupManagementType AzureVM -Name "<BackupItemName>" `
  -VaultId $targetVault.ID
Enable-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtection -Item $anotherBkpItem `
  -Policy $TargetPol1 -VaultId $targetVault.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

In the current backup policy for particular VM, enter the "Associated items" menu. Search for the VM and select "View details". Then, click on the "Backup policy" which will open the "Change backup policy" window where you can select whatever backup policy you want to be applied to the VM.

Comment: i miss the source to prove that